# Sort values based on colors, then on values using VBA code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm tryin to sort values based on colors, then on values

The macro was working very well, but on one sheet, so I have to create a new module for each sheet, and because I have around 400 sheets,

This is the simple working macro:

```
    Sub A_Sort()
'
' A_Sort Macro
'

'
    Range("B4:J43").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(169, _
        208, 142)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(244, _
        176, 132)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(184, _
        137, 219)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(155, _
        194, 230)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("G4:G43") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B3:J43")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("B4:B43").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B4:B43") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_3").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B4:B43")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("C4").Select
```

The best way is to run the macro for the active sheet, not for a named sheet

This my try, but it's not working, I don't know how to re-write the code to work on the active sheet

```
Sub A_Sort()
'
' A_Sort Macro
'

'
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    With WS.Sort
    Range("B4:J43").Select
    WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(169, _
        208, 142)
    WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(244, _
        176, 132)
   WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(184, _
        137, 219)
    WS.Range("G3:G43")).Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B4:B43"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(155, _
        194, 230)
   WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("G4:G43") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B3:J43")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("B4:B43").Select
    WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B4:B43") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With WS.Range("G3:G43").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B4:B43")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("C4").Select
End Sub
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Some of your "Range" commands are missing the `WS.` prefix.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, I don't have that experience in VBA, could you please explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works.
You seem to misunderstand what "With" does. When you encapsulate everything with "With WS", you don't have to use the "WS." prefix anymore. All you need is "."

```
Sub A_Sort()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    
    With WS
        .Range("B4:J43").Select
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("B4:B43"), _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(169, _
            208, 142)
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("B4:B43"), _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(244, _
            176, 132)
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("B4:B43"), _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(184, _
            137, 219)
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("B4:B43"), _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(155, _
            194, 230)
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("G4:G43") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange WS.Range("B3:J43")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        .Range("B4:B43").Select
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("B4:B43") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange WS.Range("B4:B43")
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        .Range("C4").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know how to upload a screen shot here, anyway unfortunately it's not working
Check this link please 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f44tqj23rtj74jg/A_Sort.png?dl=0

Comment: @SaherNaji Can you try again with the current code in the answer? I updated it like 3 times. Sorry about that. I don't know if you tried the latest version.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working very well

Comment: The time order as shown in the screenshot in the dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f44tqj23rtj74jg/A_Sort.png?dl=0
for the first 3 colors (4:00-22:00) every thing is working well, but the current code sorting the times like this for the last period (22:00 - 4:00): 02:30; 03:00, 22:00, but it should to start with 22:00 and ends with 03:59
So could we add some lines to this part of code to sort the times correctly:
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("G4:G43") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

Comment: @SaherNaji this is difficult for me to say as to be honest, I really have no idea what your macro does. All I did was take your "working macro" and adapted it to work for ActiveSheet. Maybe try "Order:=xlDescending" ?

Comment: Thanks, I'm will try